# Php File Upload and Download to localhost Server

Tags: php, html, pdf, xampp

The problem is;
I have uploaded a Picture,PPTX and Pdf file to database server.
Its done easily but issue is:

When i tried with a Picture, it was shown in the browser.
But
When i view that PDF file, it automatically gets downloaded.

I tried using PPTX; Same result it too automatically gets downloaded.

Comment: if pdf or pptx, what you want to do??

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the images the browsers show the pictures. But they have no support on PPTX and pdf files.

For pdf avoid using direct link. use

```
<object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="myfile.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

For PPTX try [Embed a Presentation on Your Site](http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/powerpoint-embed.aspx)